# Theano: expected 2, got 1 with shape (128,).')

Tags: machine-learning, theano

Im trying to make a neural network. I have followed the video from

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S75EdAcXHKk

I have loaded the adult.data training set.

I am now on my way of training and i have these lines where the code fails.

```
while(epocs<5):
            i = 0
            for start, end in zip(range(0, len(trX), 128), range(128, len(trX), 128)):
                print(trX.shape)
                tr = trX[start:end]
                print(tr.shape[0])
                print(tr.shape[1])
                self.cost = train(tr.reshape(tr.shape[0],tr.shape[1]), trY[start:end])
            epocs+=1
```

I am strugling with an error message which is:

```
n.training()
```

File "C:\Users\Bjornars\PycharmProjects\cogs-118a\Project\NN\Network.py", line 101, in training
    self.cost = train(tr.reshape(128,106), trY[start:end])
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 513, in **call**
    allow_downcast=s.allow_downcast)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\type.py", line 169, in filter
    data.shape))
TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "C:\Users\Bjornars\PycharmProjects\cogs-118a\Project\NN\Network.py:84"  at index 1(0-based)', 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 2, got 1 with shape (128,).')

The shape of the array im sending in is (5000,106)

---Solved----

Comment: and what is the size of trY?

Comment: The size of TrY is 5000, the same as the trX.

If it is wanted I can upload a bitbucket link for the repo so you can run it?

Comment: The error might be related to try not trx

Comment: Thank you so much. Can i give you a plus somewhere? 

It wanted an array instead of 0,1 it wanted [0,1]. With this saying that number one is predicted.

Comment: glad I coud help - just accept your own answer, this is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this, it expected array not number in trY

```
    def preprocess(self,trDmatrix,labels):
          for i in range(len(trDmatrix)):
              numbers = [0.0]*2
              numbers[int(labels[i])]= 1.0
              labels[i] = numbers
          return trDmatrix, labels
```